# DOCTYPE not recognized on Linux Server (only in IE)

Tags: php, linux, internet-explorer, doctype

Im facing issue I have never seen before.

So, I have two apache servers, one is **Win64 PHP 7.3.4 TS**, other is **Linux x86_64 PHP 7.2.5 NT**S.

index.php on first line contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

when I load the page on **Win64 php ts** server, all works fine (in IE, Edge, Chrome), but when I load the exactly same code on **Linux** server, only Edge and Chrome works finem **IE** doesnt show any CSS and lot of other JS or HTML stuff.

I have noticed, that only in IE on Linux server, it cant detect doctime, and when i try to see sourcecode on IE for that linux server webpage, it shows me "`<!--DOCTYPE html>`" instead of "`<!DOCTYPE html>`", on other server or other browsers, it shows correctly.

It must be something on serverside, otherwise i cant explain why the same file works on different servers, just not thisone...

the index.php contains only:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

Comment: Did you check the `Page Source` to see if the server actually served the DOCTYPE line?

Comment: yes, the index.php file is mine, the content of the file you can see in the post above

Comment: Did you check the **Page Source** from the browsers that work and the ones that dont ? And did you compare the 2 to see if anything is missing OR not

Comment: Yes, on IE, EDGE, CHROME on Win64 server shows correctly <!DOCTYPE html>, and CHROME, EDGE on Linux shows correctly <!DOCTYPE html>, only IE on Linux server shows <!--DOCTYPE html-->

Comment: Is it because you don't have a well-formed HTML document, and it is reverting to XML/XHTML and then stopping rendering at the error? (you are outputting text outside of <html>. It's just a thought.

Comment: Download the HTML from the server using a tool that can get it into a file without mangling it in any way (`wget` is a good choice). Then open it up in a hex editor and check for rogue bytes before the Doctype. If there are any, that will give you a lead for debugging it.

Comment: Jeff: not true, when index.php would show ONLY line <!DOCTYPE html> then Im getting same issue

Comment: Are you using some kind of web site that provides some environment to test with multiple browsers or you are testing with actual browsers? Try to again upload the web page and test the issue. Check whether this issue occurs with all the sites hosted on that server or issue related with this specific site.

Comment: Thanks all to comments, I have checked the browser version output, and it showed IE7 instead of IE11, so I realized the website was added to compatibility view long time ago which i did not remember. When removing from compatibility, all works fine

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all to comments, I have checked the browser version output, and it showed IE7 instead of IE11, so I realized the website was added to compatibility view long time ago which i did not remember. When removing from compatibility, all works fine